# MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE is reading '/run/secrets/mypassword' as the password not the path

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

It suppose to treat it as a path. But it is thinking "/run/secrets/mypassword" is the actual password. "_FILE" is already used.

I have tried give '' to it. It is still not working

When I go to /run/secrets/mypassword, I can see secret file and inside the file is the correct password.

Below is my docker-compose.yml.Anyone can give some advice, please? Thank you very much

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10.6'
        working_dir: /application2
        volumes:
            - '.:/application2'
            - db1:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE : /run/secrets/mypassword
            MYSQL_DATABASE: db1
            MYSQL_USER: user1
            MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE : /run/secrets/mypassword2
        secrets:
            - mypassword
            - mypassword2
        ports:
            - '21003:3306'
        networks:
            - app2
secrets:
    mypassword:
        file: mypassword.txt
    mypassword2:
        file: mypassword2.txt
```

Comment: `ls -lA /run/secrets/mypassword` Your docker user needs access rights to the file.Is that given?

Comment: Be aware that the environment variables are only used if no database exists when the container starts. You map a volume to /var/lib/mysql, so chances are that you already have a database and then it'll use the password defined in that. Try and remove the volume mapping and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The permission is 664. The owner and its group is both 1000

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks! it is as you say. I have remove and recreate the volume. now it is working very well. Thank you!

Comment: @ehku Great. I've turned my comment into an answer. If you accept it, someone else with the same problem might find it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that the environment variables are only used if no database exists when the container starts. You map a volume to `/var/lib/mysql`, so chances are that you already have a database and then it'll use the password defined in that.

Try and remove the volume mapping and see if it works.